# How to load fonts in css while using webpack?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webpack

My relevant portion of my project directory looks like this:

```
root    
  --src      
    --js    
    --styles    
      --less
        --main.less
      --fonts
        --Pixelated.tff
  --webpack.config.js
```

This is the relevant portion of my `webpack.config.js`

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: [ 'babel' ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    }, {
      test: /\.less?$/,
      loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'less' ],
      include: __dirname
    },
    {test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }]
  }
};
```

In main.less, this is the relevant @font-face portion:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pixelated';
  src: url('../fonts/Pixelated.ttf');
}
```

I've tried a couple of variations on the webpack loader with various github issues I've looked over to no avail. I've also tried using the absolute path to my `tff` font file just for proof of concept and that isn't working either, which I imagine must be related to my webpack setup.

Comment: did you try the file-loader :      {test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/Pixelated.tff` on the build

Comment: can you provide a piece of your code throw github or other to play a little bit hard to say like that. Where the webpack.config.js is located ?

Comment: It's at the project root - what other code might help? I have the related parts of my css and webpack config in the OP - not really sure where else in my codebase this issue could be coming from

Comment: Is this the whole webpack config ? Do you have an entry point and output ?

Comment: While I understand the temptation, just don't pack fonts? Being able to rely on browser cache for these resources is *far* more efficient for your users. Also, it looks like you're still stuck in a few years ago in terms of @font-face sources. Every currently supported browser supports WOFF. Don't use the other formats, you'll just make your deploy needlessly bigger (and EOT and SVG have literally been abandoned)

Comment: Added the rest of the webpack.config.js

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - the issue exists even if I'm using a hosted version of the file, but I was trying a locally duplicated version since I'd like to tinker around with this while I'm offline. Can you elaborate on WOFF? I was just googling 8-bit/pixelated fonts and the one I downloaded was a TTF file so I rolled with that

Comment: I can indeed. http://caniuse.com/#search=woff for the browser insight, and https://www.google.ca/search?q=convert+ttf+to+woff for (quite a few!) free ways to convert your `ttf` to a `woff` file instead. ttf/otf are general OpenType fonts (difference between the vector language used for letter shapes; truetype vectors vs. type2 vectors), converting them to WOFF optimises them for use on the web while also making it clear to the browser that the font is *intended* for web use, not just "a random font I found" (not always true of course =)

Comment: @Jimmy Gong, have you fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
 {
      test: /\.less?$/,
      loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'less' ],
      include: __dirname
  },
```

to

```
{
    test: /(\.less|\.css)$/,
    loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'less' ],
}
```

It should work, the main.css file is a css and you need to use an appropriate loader for that type of files.

Comment: I should have mentioned it before, I wound up changing to .less over the course of asking this question. main.css is now main.less

Comment: I made a little project for me if it is a less file your config should work as it is : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kwfcfbuq0spc2ew/AADxYK4Sql3kw5Q7UcBv1E-Ua/test-css?dl=0 

I made a main.js file in src/js that require the main.less which load the .ttf

Comment: Hm, no substantial differences  I can see. I wonder if the issue is somewhere else. Thanks for the efforts though, I really appreciate it